# Problem with bluehost not sending my emails while it works perfectly fine on localhost

Tags: email, bluehost

i am using codeigniter3 on a real estate website that has an email functionality. When I test it on localhost, it works perfectly but when i upload it to bluehost, email does not send.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjhnU.jpg)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi, i have posted the question on this thread with codes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276842/gmail-smtp-does-not-work-on-bluehost-but-works-on-localhost